# Is Creatine illegal in Australia?

Tags: supplements, creatine

I've done little bit of research on it and saw few links talking about Creatine is banned in Australia. Is that really true? I need to take health-examination before I return to Australia, are they going to refuse me for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[No](http://forum.simplyshredded.com/topic/4630/australia-banning-creatine-help/). [DMAA was banned](https://www.tga.gov.au/behind-news/tga-decision-ban-dmaa) in 2012, but not creatine.